# how to store special character '{' and '}' in StringBuilder.AppendFormat

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am creating one Project using **RESTFUL WEBSERVICES** but in the url when I am giving

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/RestfulWebservicesNewVersion2/REST/webservices/GetFriend"
```

I am getting this output:

```
"\u0027EmployeeList\u0027:{{\u0027emp_id\u0027:\u00272\u0027,\u0027emp_ename\u0027:

\u0027rkjha\u0027,\u0027emp_phoneno\u0027:\u00273232323232\u0027,\u0027emp_email\u0027
```

Can you tell me how could I will remove the "U0027 " part.

Comment: thanks irrelephant for editing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.text.normalizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to remove Unicode characters that are not in the "normal" ASCII character set.